# Problem running gulp task 'buildFonts' to export PDF with HTML icons

Tags: pdf, gulp, task, pdfmake

I'm working with JQuery Datatables (v1.10.18) in an ASP NET Project with WebForms.
**Being concise, I'm trying to export the table to PDF. It works fine. The only problem I have is that in some tables, there're some HTML icons like 'fa fa-check' which are not shown in the PDF.**

It's worth mentioning I set

```
stripHtml: false,
```

I'm following the steps described in https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/fonts/custom-fonts-client-side/#1-create-a-new-vfs-fonts-js-containing-your-font-files

However, I cannot make it work. The step 'Run gulp buildFonts to create a new build/vfs_fonts.js (you can update gulpfile.js to change the base directory path or to add an alternative config for the buildFonts task).' is giving me problems.

*It's good to know is the first time I use 'gulp' so I was guiding myself through examples I found on the web and in the documentation of gulp and pdfmake*

I define the file 'gulpFile.js' in the folder 'pdfmake-0.1.36' (which is the folder that contains the pdfmake.js and vfs_fonts.js scripts needed to export to PDF).

Then, in 'gulpFile.js' I define:

```
    const gulp = require('gulp');
    const gulpFont = require('gulp-font');

    gulp.task('buildFonts', function () {
    console.log('starts');
    gulp.src('/examples/fonts/.{ttf,otf}', { read: false })
    .pipe(gulpFont({
        ext: '.css',
        fontface: '/examples/fonts/',
        relative: '/examples/fonts/',
        dest: '/examples/fonts/',
        embed: ['woff'],
        collate: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/examples/fonts/'));
    console.log('finishes');
  });
```

In '/examples/fonts/' is placed the 'fontawesome' font which I want to use to export the HTML icons.

Then, in cmd I go to the specific folder and execute

```
gulp buildFonts
```

And it prints out

```
starts
finishes
The following tasks did not complete: buildFonts
Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

This gulps tasks is supposed to create a new 'vfs_fonts.js' in a new folder 'pdfmake-0.1.36/build/' but it isn't creating anything.

Comment: Just put a "return" statement before the "gulp.src….."

Comment: ok but what I'm suppose to return?

Comment: Just put it right before the gulp.src… so "return gulp.src('examples...…… without the quotes of course.  You are returning the stream that gulp.src creates.

Comment: I'd like to know which is the aim of doing that. Is just for cheking issue or it's obligatory for the function?

Comment: It is one way to "signal async completion" which is why your buildFonts doesn't complete.  Search for "signal async completion" and you will find a lot.

Comment: When it says 'Run gulp buildFonts to create a new build/vfs_fonts.js (you can update gulpfile.js to change the base directory path or to add an alternative config for the buildFonts task).' I understand there is a way to execute the 'buildFonts' task without defining it by myself. It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const gulpFont = require('gulp-font');

gulp.task('buildFonts', async function () {
    console.log('starts');
    await gulp.src('/examples/fonts/.{ttf,otf}', { read: false })
          .pipe(gulpFont({
              ext: '.css',
              fontface: '/examples/fonts/',
              relative: '/examples/fonts/',
              dest: '/examples/fonts/',
              embed: ['woff'],
              collate: false
          }))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('/examples/fonts/'));
  console.log('finishes');
});
```

add async fo function and await for gulp